# using htaccess for public and private directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

Directory structure for my website is like this:

- www/

  - PSite/

    - inc/
    - public/

[image]

The inc(include) directory is for where i will include all the important and secure PHP files where normally users have no access but only php code from the public directory can access into the inc directory.
And in public direcotry i will have all public files and pages. 
I have heared that it's a better security system, and i want to do it using `.htaccess` file.
Assume i have a `.htaccess` file in the **PSite** directory how i can redirect request at **PSite** to **/public/index.html** so, users will be unable to reach at **inc** directory? i was trying with this code, but it dosen't works with other files and folders in **public** directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php [L]
```

**Note that i have changed the path: localhost/PSite with psite.dev using httpd.conf and windows host file**
HTTPD Conf:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   ServerName psite.dev
   DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\PSite"
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Whats the problem with your current .htaccess code?

Comment: if i go to psite.dev then only the index.html file works and other directories and files inside /public directory shows 404 not found.

Comment: Thats what you have told it to do. Is there any file name **index.php** in your public directory? And what directories you are talking about?

Comment: well, say i have another file like users.php in public directory now if i go to psite.dev/users.php then it shows a 404 error

Comment: Your current htaccess is wrong then. You are internally mapping all requests to index.php no matter what you are requesting from your URL it will always request to `index.php`. Well this is even possible with your currently virtual host configuration. Please include the contents of your **httpd.conf**

Comment: Change your **DocumentRoot** to `DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\PSite\public"` and try again without your htaccess contents (remove it). By the way your htaccess isn't functional by seeing your `httpd.conf` file though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put in the directory to deny access an .htaccess file containing

```
deny from all
```

If you have a sub-directory containing public files insert another .htaccess with

```
allow from all
```